# How to handle space in condition in SQL Loader?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have a dat file to load to the database.
My code is as below.

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'ABC.DAT'
APPEND
INTO TABLE RECORDS WHEN (COL1 ='F')
(
COL1 POSITION(1:1),
 COL2 POSITION(2:6),
 ...
)
INTO TABLE RECORDS WHEN (COL1 =' ')
(

COL1 POSITION(1:1),
COL3 POSITION(2:6),
 ...
)
```

First condition works fine but second when clause always fails.
I tried checking it with COL1 !-'F' but that doesn't help either.

Does anyone have an idea on how to handle space in when clause?

Comment: have you tried col1 is null?

Comment: have you tried trimming it & checking for empty string : _TRIM(COL1)=''_

Comment: I checked with col1 is null but doesn't work

Comment: Trim doesn't help either

Comment: You state it always fails.  Whats the error?  Or does it just not load those rows where column 1 is a space?  Show the log file, it may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Structure your when clause to test the character by position instead of the column name like this:

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'ABC.DAT'
APPEND
INTO TABLE RECORDS WHEN (1) = 'F'
(
COL1 POSITION(1:1),
 COL2 POSITION(2:6),
 ...
)
INTO TABLE RECORDS WHEN (1) = ' '
(

COL1 POSITION(1:1),
COL3 POSITION(2:6),
 ...
)
```